# Flot chart only displaying first series data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, flot

I'm using flot and with the JSON returned, and the initialzation provided, only the first series is visible on the chart, however, the legend displays all 3 series labels.  Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
var data = [];

    function onDataReceived(seriesData) {

        var options = {
            series: { stack: false,
                lines: { show: true, steps: false },
                bars: { show: false, barWidth: 0.5, align: 'center', horizontal: true },
                points: { show: true, radius: 3, symbol: 'circle' }
            },
            yaxis: { show: true, tickLength: 0 },
            xaxis: { tickSize: [1, "month"], tickLength: 0, mode: 'time', timeformat: '%b %y' },
            legend: { show: true, container: $('#@(ctlId)chartLegend'), noColumns: 3 },
            grid: { borderWidth: 0, hoverable: true, clickable: true }

        };


        var p = $.plot($('#@(ctlId)'), seriesData.seriesData, options);
```

And My MVC Handler:

```
return Json(new
        {
            axisNames = new List<string[]>() { },
            seriesData = new[]
        {
            new {
            color = "#e17009",
            label = "RN",
            data = new List<string[]>() {
                new string[] {DateTime.Parse("7/12/2012", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).GetJavascriptTimestamp().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "4.2"},
                new string[] {DateTime.Parse("8/12/2012", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).GetJavascriptTimestamp().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "4.8"},
                new string[] {DateTime.Parse("9/12/2012", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).GetJavascriptTimestamp().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "2.5"},
                new string[] {DateTime.Parse("10/12/2012", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).GetJavascriptTimestamp().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "5.0"},
                new string[] {DateTime.Parse("11/12/2012", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).GetJavascriptTimestamp().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "3.6"}
                }
            },
            new {
            color = "#ff0000",
            label = "RA",
            data = new List<string[]>() {
                new string[] {DateTime.Parse("7/12/2012", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).GetJavascriptTimestamp().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "3.2"},
                new string[] {DateTime.Parse("8/12/2012", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).GetJavascriptTimestamp().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "3.8"},
                new string[] {DateTime.Parse("9/12/2012", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).GetJavascriptTimestamp().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "3.5"},
                new string[] {DateTime.Parse("10/12/2012", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).GetJavascriptTimestamp().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "2.0"},
                new string[] {DateTime.Parse("11/12/2012", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).GetJavascriptTimestamp().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "2.6"}
                }
            }
            ,
            new {
            color = "#5c9ccc",
            label = "RA",
            data = new List<string[]>() {
                new string[] {DateTime.Parse("7/12/2012", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).GetJavascriptTimestamp().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "2.2"},
                new string[] {DateTime.Parse("8/12/2012", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).GetJavascriptTimestamp().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "2.8"},
                new string[] {DateTime.Parse("9/12/2012", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).GetJavascriptTimestamp().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "2.5"},
                new string[] {DateTime.Parse("10/12/2012", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).GetJavascriptTimestamp().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "1.0"},
                new string[] {DateTime.Parse("11/12/2012", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).GetJavascriptTimestamp().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "2.4"}
                }
            }
        }
        },
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: What is `GetJavascriptTimestamp`? How do you get `seriesData` into your `onDataReceived` method?

Comment: It's a static function that converts the datetime to a flot friendly format.  A jQuery ajax call handles the loading of data.  See below for my solution, it was related to a flot configuration oddity.

Comment: Strange... I've copied your code an empty project and it worked perfectly fine, it rendered all the 3 series... even with `stack: false`. jquery-1.7.1 jplot referenced from github

Comment: @nemesv, that is odd indeed.  My only thought is that I'm referencing the flot stacked plugin, which is what I suspect gives that setting life.  I'm using stacked bar charts on other parts of the page.

Comment: Now if I reference `jquery.flot.stack.js` I get one series if I have `stack: false` and get the correct 3 series if I remove the `stack: false` so you should add this info to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this worked out.  Flot does not seem to want to render more than one series with the use of the `stack: false` option when it is set to false and you are also referencing the `jquery.flot.stack.js` plugin.  Removing the `stack` attribute in the code below resolved my issue.  If you are not referencing the stack plugin, you can keep the `stack: false` attribute and it will display the additional series properly as well.  Hope it helps someone.

The returned JSON was correct.

```
var data = [];

function onDataReceived(seriesData) {

    var options = {
        series: { 
            lines: { show: true, steps: false },
            bars: { show: false, barWidth: 0.5, align: 'center', horizontal: true },
            points: { show: true, radius: 3, symbol: 'circle' }
        },
        yaxis: { show: true, tickLength: 0 },
        xaxis: { tickSize: [1, "month"], tickLength: 0, mode: 'time', timeformat: '%b %y' },
        legend: { show: true, container: $('#@(ctlId)chartLegend'), noColumns: 3 },
        grid: { borderWidth: 0, hoverable: true, clickable: true }

    };


    var p = $.plot($('#@(ctlId)'), seriesData.seriesData, options);
```